# how to make multipe selectable checkboxes using React,GraphQL,Apollo

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo

I'm making multiple selectable checkboxes using React, GraphQL, Apollo.

I would like to make a query if it is selected, insert query and unselected, delete query(I want to generate a query only for selected/removed items)

Right now I'm making it using mutation but I have a problem where everything is deleted and then inserted.

I would like to generate a query only for selected/removed items. How can I fix it?

My code is as follows.

```
const [updateNoteMutation] = useUpdateNoteMutation();
const updateLogic = (key: string, value: string | number | Condition[]) => {
  const noteVariables = {
     variables: {
       id: noteData.id,
       noteAttributes: {
         [key]: value,
       },
     },
  };
  updateNoteMutation(noteVariables).then(({ errors }) => {});
});
```

const handleCollection = (name: string, arr: Array) => {
//arr: List of selected checkboxes.
const noteArr = [];
diff.map((val) => {
noteArr.push({ name: val });
});
updateLogic(name, noteArr);
};

```
updateNoteMutation
```

mutation UpdateNote($id: ID!, $noteAttributes: FemappNoteInput!) {
femappUpdateNote(input: {id: $id, noteAttributes: $noteAttributes}) {
note {
id
checkboxList {
name
}
}
}
}

```
Please let me know if there is a source code that I can refer to

Thanks for reading my question.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `react-select` for that. Really easy to implement and fully customizable.
Here is the repo;
https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select